# Can't push feature branch in git, doesn't exist in remote?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I created a feature branch off of develop.  It looks like this:

[image: feature]

Previously when I made a feature branch, it also showed up on the remote, but now it's not present.  Now, when I try to push in SourceTree, I get the following error:

```
To https://myname-mycompany@bitbucket.org/mycompany/projectname.git
 ! [remote rejected] feature/data_utilities -> feature/data_utilities (failed to write)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://myname-mycompany@bitbucket.org/mycompany/projectname.git'
```

I also tried the command line...

```
git push origin feature/data_utilities
```

...but I got the same results.  When I look on BitBucket, the feature branch doesn't exist.

Comment: Possibly related because I deleted a feature branch previously: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/9288/cannot-reuse-an-old-branch-prefix-as-a

Answer (score 2):

I don't use BitBucket, but the process for creating a feature branch from the command line is very simple.

```
git checkout develop
git checkout -B feature_branch
  # This command creates a new branch and switches context to the newly created branch
git push -u origin feature_branch
  # This will create the branch on origin and set it up to be a tracking branch
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but there is something really broken with sourcetree (I think related to the link above).  When I delete the feature branch, then create it again off of develop, it stays based off of master.

Comment: Understood. Best of luck :/