# BitBucket push to feature branch model

Tags: git, bitbucket

I created a new branch on bitbucket server (private hosted). Bitbucket have multiple branch types like "hotfixes", "feature", etc. I created one using the "feature" branch model. The branch name in the branch list became "feature/mybranchname". 
I do the usual `git fetch`, `git checkout -b mybranchname origin/feature/mybranchname` and start working.

But the problem is that whatever new changes i made in the branch "mybranchname" cannot be pushed to the remote. Whenever `git push` executed, only *master* will get updated, even though the git status says X commits ahead of "origin/feature/mybranchname".

`git push -u origin mybranchname` will create a new branch on the server without the "feature" name, therefore it's duplicated into a new branch.

`git push feature/mybranchname` will return the following.

```
fatal: 'feature/mybranchname' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

```

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864292/cant-push-feature-branch-in-git-doesnt-exist-in-remote) similar question, but without any solution.
Found [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-branches-in-bitbucket-server-776639968.html) documentation from atlassian stating what is branching model and such, but without any mentioning of how to push to them.

Expected result: the local commits from "mybranchname" gets pushed to remote's "feature/mybranchname" without doing a merge from the web UI.

Comment: Did you try to check the branch is exist? `git checkout feature/mybranchname`

Comment: I used `git checkout -b mybranchname feature/mybranchname` and it can't push. But when I simply do `git checkout feature/mybranchname`, it works. Would you like to change it to answer?

Comment: yes. I posted my answer

Comment: I have posted *why* this is the right option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `git checkout feature/mybranchname`

And create new branch with `git checkout -b mybranchname`

And `git push -u origin mybranchname`

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the remote repo:

```
gut push -u origin feature/mybranchname
```

Then your local `feature/mybranchname` will be linked to its remote tracking counterpart `origin/feature/mybranchname`, and a simple `git push` will then be enough.

The OP adds:

> I created a new branch using `git checkout -b mybranchname feature/mybranchname` but instead it should be just `git checkout feature/mybranchname`

Yes, because the [git checkout man page mentions](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt):

> ### `git checkout <branch>`
>
> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it ) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to

```
git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

Note that in that case, you do *not need* `git push -u origin feature/mybranchname`: again, a simple `git push` is enough, since the local branch is already linked to the remote tracking branch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was the first thing I tried, it only update the remote/master, didn't update the feature branch. Apparently, @Tang Duong's comment gave me the solution. I created a new branch using `git checkout -b mybranchname feature/mybranchname` but instead it should be just `git checkout feature/mybranchname` and it setup the tracking and everything fine.

Comment: @ThuYeinTun I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, as well as the relevant portion of the git checkout man page which explains why this works.